# lisp debugging in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to walk through the Parenscript library to see how it renders, i.e. what actually happens when you make a `(ps... )` call.

Ideally, I'd use VSCode to set breakpoints and watches and step into all called functions. There doesn't seem to be any lisp debugging extension in the VSCode marketplace.

Right now, I'm loading sbcl in a terminal window in VSCode and have `command-shift-A` bound to `Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal`, so that anything I write in the editor can be executed in sbcl.

Is there a way to set up the VSCode environment so that I can have access to debugging tools like watches and step-into?

Comment: Just in case, the SLIMA Atom plugin is very good and has the interactive debugger. https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#text-editor-resources

Comment: Just installed SLIMA in atom, had a question or two -- for instance, how do I use the interactive features in the attached REPL?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can click the restart buttons or choose them with `0`, `1` etc. But don't hesitate to ask on their Github/IRC, I just tried it quickly.